# How to fetch more row from a pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Hi I am trying to build an app where there are parent elements which have children and each child has its own sub child. I am having a pivot table which consists of user_id, plan_id and child_id, Now I am trying to fetch the child. How can I fetch all the children in an array.:

I am trying following code:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$selectplan = 1;
$children = $user->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->first()->pivot->child;
```

I am able to get only first child, but I have more rows to be fetched:

```
/**** Table Column ****
*
*
/--id----user_id----plan_id----child----created_at----updated_at
    1        1         1         2        NULL          NULL
    1        1         2         3        NULL          NULL
    1        1         1         4        NULL          NULL
    1        2         1         7        NULL          NULL
    1        2         1         8        NULL          NULL
    1        2         3         10       NULL          NULL
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first` only returns a single model instance; the first one matching the query constraints. In order to return a collection you need to use `get`

```
$children = $user->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get()->pivot->child;
```